# Find if relation is reflexive, symmetric or transitive

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, relations

Let $A = \{1, 2, 3, 4\}$ and let $F$ be the set of all functions from $A$ to $A$. Let $R$ be the relation on $F$ defined by 
"For all $f, g$ in $F$, $(f, g)$ in $R$ if and only if $f (i) = g (i)$ for some $i$ in $A$."

Let $N, S$ in $F$ be the functions defined by $N(x) = 1$ and $S(x) = 2$ for all $x$ in $A$.

Is $R$ reflexive? Symmetric? Transitive? Please help me through this problem, I don't think it's either because there is no way $N(x) = S(x)$, but it's obviously not right.

Comment: It's reflexive and symmetric, but not transitive.

Comment: Thank you, can you let me know how you could got that?

Comment: It looks like another "James" has essentially summarised what you need to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $f\sim g$ if $(f,g)\in R$.

For reflexivity of $R$, you need to check whether $f\sim f$ for all $f\in F$.

For symmetry of $R$, you need to check whether, for all $f,g\in F$, it holds that $f\sim g$ implies $g\sim f$.

For transitivity of $R$, you need to check whether $f\sim g$ and $g\sim h$ implies $f\sim h$ for arbitrary $f,g,h\in F$.

Since this looks like home work, I will refrain from posting the concrete answer.

Comment: Ok thank you I'm trying to piece it together, I am just getting confused by f(x)=g(x) where N(x) does not equal S(x) N is 1 and S is 2. Unless I only concentrate on the domain, I can see that it is reflexive (1,1) and (1,2) xRx, But unless I can change the co domain, I can't tell how it is symmetric...Am I at least on the right track, haha?

Comment: Your functions $N(i) = 1$ and $S(i) = 2$ don't really tell you anything about reflexivity, symmetry, and transitivity of $R$. Note that $f\sim g$ if and only if $f(i) = g(i)$ for some $i$, so $N\not\sim S$. 

I'll get you started on proving the properties by showing you how to do it for reflexivity. It's really quite easy:

"For any $f\in F$, $f(i) = f(i)$ for all $i$, in particular $f(1) = f(1)$, whereby $f\sim f$. Hence $R$ is reflexive."

You prove (or disprove) the remaining properties in a similar way.